# Display Advanced custom fields on a theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I'm new to ACF, and for practice purpose, I have created a custom post type and successfully assigned it with advanced custom fields.
now my next challenge is to display a specific custom field in my home page theme.
For that matter, on GP theme using Finance Demo, I'm trying to replace the 'Katka Finance' title on the homepage hero with my own custom field. which file I need to edit and what should I insert?
thank you all in advance!

https://generatepress.com/site-library/[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't downloaded the demo itself but I can tell you because it's the homepage it should either be in front-page.php or it should be in a homepage template.

The title will could be included in a couple of different ways, so instead we are going to look for similar wrappers, look for this:

```
<h1 class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default">...</h1>
```

You may find that the below, is in between the 2 h1 tags

```
<?php the_title();?>
```

That's what you need to edit.

First, make a custom field and make it either a textbox, textarea or WYSIWYG editor. Fill in the fields, in my example, I will say I named it Homepage Heading (homepage_heading). Now replace the above code with the following:

```
<?php the_field('homepage_heading');?>
```

Then populate the field in the post/page editor with what you want the title to be. This should work.